# Unable to set proper conditional statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, addeventlistener, innerhtml, getelementbyid

Please can someone kindly help on this, since 22nd, May. I really wanna know what's wrong with the if-statement

Full-code at
https://code.sololearn.com/W6I2TCWqa5En/#

I wrote the following **if condition** so that if the the td is empty the innerHTML should be '0'. But even when the innerHTML is "X" and not ''(empty), it still change the (X) to 0.

Declaring the values of zero, one, two:

```
var w=2;
var zero=document.getElementById ('game0');
var one=document.getElementById ('game1');
var two=document.getElementById ('game2');
```

This first condition is meant to turn the first empty space to X and then move to the second part of the code below:

```
if(w==2 && zero.innerHTML=='  '){

  zero.innerHTML='X';

  w=1;

}

else if(w==2 && one.innerHTML=='   '){

  one.innerHTML='X';

  w=1;
}
  else if(w==2 && two.innerHTML=='   '){

  two.innerHTML='X';

  w=1;
}
```

But still after the first condition has been applied on the first empty space which is the zero.innerHTML
and the condition then moves to the below code and is meant to only work if **w=1 and zero/one/two. innerHTML is empty**

The condition works for only  case 1 (zero.innerHTML) but not for the the other condition  as my touch still changes the automatically input 'X' to  '0' for either one.innerHTML or two.innerHTML

```
if(w==1 && zero.innerHTML==''){

  zero.addEventListener('click',function(){

    zero.innerHTML='O';

    w=2;
  })
}
if(w==1 && one.innerHTML==''){
   one.addEventListener('click',function(){

    one.innerHTML='O';

    w=2;
  })
}
if(w==1 && two.innerHTML==''){
   two.addEventListener('click',function(){

    two.innerHTML='O';

    w=2;
  })
}
```

Please how do i fix  the condition so that it doesn't change the 'X' to '0' for the (one/two.innerHTML)

Please any help will be appreciated because I'm confused

Comment: Properly indented code would be more readable.

Comment: yes I have made the code more readable, please your help would be appreciation